# Set default attribute for all Kendo UI Grids

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Web Site containing multiple Kendo UI Grids. I have now been asked to remove the scrollbar from each of these grids. I know there's a config attribute `scrollable` that I could change to `false` in order to achieve this.

However, I would like to avoid adding this attribute to every grid. Doesn't seem right. I could look for a way to achieve this using CSS but seems unnecessary.

I know this is doable in other Kendo UI Grid controls like the Editor. For instance, one could hide options from the toolbar like this:

```
var defaultTools = kendo.ui.Editor.defaultTools;
defaultTools.formatting = {}; 
defaultTools.insertImage = {};
```

I haven't found something similar for the Kendo UI Grid control. Is there a way to change default value for this attribute to `true`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an all or nothing change, but will do just that.

Set the default options for the scrollable to false

```
kendo.ui.Grid.fn.options.scrollable = false;
```

You will want to set that before any kendo grids are created.